# Is there a way to create a print function on my asp website?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I'm using asp classic and I want to print my page.It is like a report website I tried saving it as .doc but It is not saving the corrent font size and it also save my css file. Is there any other way to print a webpage?

Comment: Don't think it's really a classic asp question.  If you put a print command in server side code then it would be sent to a printer on the server (assuming there was one)  You can always print a page by using Ctrl+P.  If you mean how can you make a page printer friendly then look at CSS solutions, you can have a special printer friendly stylesheet

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to print a webpage is by using the standard print dialog provided by the OS. Call it through JavaScript with:

```
window.print()
```

If you don't like how that's formatted, add CSS media queries. Or, for the highest degree of precision, programmatically generate a PDF with an appropriate library.